# Group By Date and SUM int - Date formatting and Order

Tags: sql-server, date, casting, group-by

I'm trying to get the SUM of the quantity sold on a day. I need the results to be in ORDER BY date. The query below gives me the exact result I need, except the date is not formatted to what I need.

```
SELECT  CAST(Datetime AS DATE) AS 'date', SUM(quantity) as total_quantity
FROM Invoice_Itemized ii
INNER JOIN Invoice_Totals it ON it.Invoice_Number = ii.Invoice_Number
WHERE ii.ItemNum = '4011'
AND it.datetime > '05/15/2015'
GROUP BY CAST(Datetime AS DATE)

SELECT DATENAME(MM, datetime) + ' ' + CAST(DAY(datetime) AS VARCHAR(2)) AS [DD Month], SUM(quantity) as total_quantity
FROM Invoice_Itemized ii
INNER JOIN Invoice_Totals it ON it.Invoice_Number = ii.Invoice_Number
WHERE ii.ItemNum = '4011'
AND it.datetime > '05/15/2015'
GROUP BY DATENAME(MM, datetime) + ' ' + CAST(DAY(datetime) AS VARCHAR(2))
```

Results for the top query:

1. 2015-05-15  91.43
2. 2015-05-16  84.77

Results for the bottom query:

1. June 1  128.34
2. June 10  85.06

The top query gives me the information I need in the order I need it by.
The bottom query gives me the date format I need but in the wrong order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need to apply different formatting, you can do it using a derived table:

```
select 
    DATENAME(MM, [date]) + ' ' + CAST(DAY([date]) AS VARCHAR(2)) AS [DD Month], 
    total_quantity 
from 
(
    SELECT  CAST([Datetime] AS DATE) AS [date], SUM(quantity) as total_quantity
    FROM Invoice_Itemized ii
    INNER JOIN Invoice_Totals it ON it.Invoice_Number = ii.Invoice_Number
    WHERE ii.ItemNum = '4011'
    AND it.[datetime] > '05/15/2015'
    GROUP BY CAST(Datetime AS DATE)
) as X
```

This way you can wrap to results into the derived table, and then apply rest of the operations on that.

I would assume this would work too, but can't test now:

```
SELECT  DATENAME(MM, CAST([datetime] AS DATE)) + ' ' 
+ CAST(DAY(CAST([datetime] AS DATE)) AS VARCHAR(2)) AS [DD Month], 
SUM(quantity) as total_quantity
FROM Invoice_Itemized ii
INNER JOIN Invoice_Totals it ON it.Invoice_Number = ii.Invoice_Number
WHERE ii.ItemNum = '4011'
AND it.[datetime] > '05/15/2015'
GROUP BY CAST([datetime] AS DATE)
```

Comment: I tested your second query. Works exactly as I needed it to. Thank you!